Schwichtenberg Physics from Symmetry p. 83 Eq 3.225
Firstly - an apology.  This is my first question to Stack Exchange and also my first attempt at using Latex.  I need to show a subscript letter with a dot above it, but can't work out how to do that and so in place of a dotted letter I am using a capital letter instead.
My question:
Using the 2x2 Identity matrix and the three Pauli matrices as a basis, Schwichtenberg generates a general Hermitian matrix which is labelled $$v_{a\dot{b}}$$ using the Van der Waerden spinor notation.  He then places the appropriate Lorentz transformation matrices to the left and right of the Hermitian matrix as shown in Eq. 3.225.
My question is why could he not have labelled the Hermitian matrix $$v_{\dot{b}a}$$ instead and reversed the positions of the two Lorentz transformation matrices?  Clearly this is not right because (I think) this gives the same answers for boosts, but delivers negative angles for rotations.
Clearly the way the Hermitian matrix is defined requires it to be labelled with the dotted letter to the right and the undotted to the left, and I note that in Eq 3.227 that is how the identity matrix and the three Pauli matrices are labelled, but I don't understand how or from where this requirement arises.
Peter

Hi Peter. I've edited your Latex to add the dotted subscript. Please check I have understood what you wanted to do correctly.

Thank you John.  That is perfect!   Peter
